# Running Kurzweil 3000 Version 15 in Batch Mode

Tags: accessibility

I'm trying to run Kurzweil 3000 Version 15 in batch mode. Kurzweil provides an "Automator" but it's not working.

It's essentially just hanging, doing nothing.

In Version 13, it used to work.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot? I've followed their instructions end-to-end, without success.

Also, is there a way for us to create a script and invoke Kurzweil 3000 from the command line? Ideally on a Mac, because I'm more familiar writing scripts in bash than windows scripts.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Maybe you can find a more specific stackexchange for electronic music and Kurzweil.

Comment: MrJLP,  electronic music and Kurzweil is a completely different topic! Also, I've a number of specific software questions where I'd like to engage with fellow developers and Assistive technologists. On shell scripts and such. Not just for Kurzweil, other assisstive technologies as well.

Comment: Oh ok. I wasn't familiar with all that. Just commented as I saw no other activity on this question

Comment: MrJLP, thank you for commenting. Kurzweil 3000 is a software that helps people who are visually challenged read online documents. I'd like to run this software in batch mode. The software itself is described at  https://www.kurzweiledu.com/k3000-firefly/overview.html